# How to calculate this triple integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was doing a physics problem and came across this integral which i need to solve

$$I(x,y,z)=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac{1}{8\pi^3}\right)\left(\frac{1-\cos(nx+my+pz))}{3-\cos(x)-\cos(y)-\cos(z)}\right)dx\,dy\,dz$$

What i want to know is that does this integral evaluate to any specific function $f(n,m,p)$, and if so then how to calculate it?

I tried Wolframalpha's triple integral calculator but that doesn't seem to work..

Are there any other online applications i can use to calculate such integrals?

Comment: Are $n$ and $m$ and $p$ integers?

Comment: Where did you get this integral? Where does it come from? The symmetry is nice and can maybe be exploited.

Comment: @Greg.Paul Yes.They are actually coordinates of a node in a 3D grid and thus can have all possible integer values
I saw this integral as a solution to a problem about calculating the equivalent resistance between nodes of an infinte N dimensional grid of unit resistors
This is the case for N=3 or an infinite 3D grid of resistors
Here is the link to the answer
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/on-this-infinite-grid-of-resistors-whats-the-equivalent-resistance

Comment: http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3719/8/11/002

Comment: @CountIblis I cant open the PDF link.Requires some sort of a login

Comment: Try here: http://sci-hub.hk/10.1088/0022-3719/8/11/002

Comment: New results here: http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/33/28/306/meta

Comment: And here: http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/35/46/307

Comment: @CountIblis I opened and read the article in the link http://sci-hub.hk/10.1088/0022-3719/8/11/002 but i could not understand much.
Is there no other way to understand the answer to this, maybe one not involving elliptic integrals or other such things?

Comment: MMA code:`f[n_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  1/(8*Pi^3)*((1 - Cos[n x + m y + p z])/(
    3 - Cos[x] - Cos[y] - Cos[z])), {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, {z, 0,
    2 Pi}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]` and `f[1, 1, 1]` gives :`0.418305`.MMA is free to use on this web page: https://develop.wolframcloud.com/ you have to only sign-in.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thankyou! It most certainly works